# Passing ClaimsPrincipal from Azure Function to BlobClient

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm creating an Azure Function as 'middleware', to open files from Azure Blob Storage directly in the browser for end users. I'm using AAD for securing the Azure Function and I'm creating SAS urls/tokens to access the blobs. So far so good. However, I want to control security of the blobcontainer with an ACL, with ADD Users and/or Groups. Therefore, I want to connect to the Blob container not with the Identity of the Azure Function, but with the Identity of the logged in user.

How can I 'pass' the logged in user to the Blob connection, so I can only create a SAS token if the user has access?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*You can make use of the codes below in your HttpTrigger Function with DefaultAzureCredential:-*

**HttpTrigger Function:-**

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

namespace FunctionApp40
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log,
            ClaimsPrincipal claimIdentity)
        {
            string endpoint = "https://<StorageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net";
            DefaultAzureCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
                new Uri(endpoint), credential);

            // Get the user's identity
            string userName = claimIdentity.Identity.Name;
            log.LogInformation($"User name: {userName}");

            // Add BlobContainerClient
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("<container-name>");

            // Get the access policy for the container
            BlobContainerAccessPolicy accessPolicy = await containerClient.GetAccessPolicyAsync();

            // Check if the user has access to the blob container
            bool hasAccess = false;
            foreach (BlobSignedIdentifier identifier in accessPolicy.SignedIdentifiers)
            {
                if (identifier.Id == userName)
                {
                    hasAccess = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (hasAccess)
            {
                // Create a SAS token with the appropriate permissions
                BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
                {
                    BlobContainerName = "test",
                    Resource = "c",
                    ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                    Protocol = SasProtocol.Https
                };
                sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read | BlobSasPermissions.Write);

                // Use the SAS token to create a BlobServiceClient object
                string sasToken = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(new StorageSharedKeyCredential("<StorageAccount-name>", "<Account-Key>")).ToString();
                BlobServiceClient sasClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"https://<StorageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net?{sasToken}"));
                
                // You can use the 'sasClient' to access the container with the SAS token.
                // Example: BlobContainerClient sasContainerClient = sasClient.GetBlobContainerClient("<container-name>");

                // Return something meaningful, such as the SAS token or a success message
                return new OkObjectResult($"SAS Token: {sasToken}");
            }

            // If the user doesn't have access, return a Forbidden status
            return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Another HttpTrigger C# code to retrieve SAS Token:-**

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionApp40
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string accountName = "valleystrg98"; // Replace with your storage account name
            string sasToken = GetAccountSASToken(accountName);

            return new OkObjectResult(sasToken);
        }

        private static string GetAccountSASToken(string accountName)
        {
            // Replace with your actual account settings
            const string ConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=valleystrg98;AccountKey=xxxxkxxxxvtVn7AxxxxL+AStdZzGlQ==";
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);

            // Create a new access policy for the account.
            SharedAccessAccountPolicy policy = new SharedAccessAccountPolicy()
            {
                Permissions = SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Read | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Write | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.List,
                Services = SharedAccessAccountServices.Blob | SharedAccessAccountServices.File,
                ResourceTypes = SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Service,
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
                Protocols = SharedAccessProtocol.HttpsOnly
            };

            // Return the SAS token.
            return storageAccount.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Browser:-**

[image]